# Is there a way I could pick up the first image in a blogpost and put it as a header in a blog post?

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

So what I'm trying to do is to get the first image in a blogpost to look like a header for every blog post page....

This is what I have so far:

```
<b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
<img expr:src ="data:post.firstImageUrl" expr:alt="data:post.title"/>
</b:if>
```

But then it's not really working. Can someone please help me out? Please see [this](http://vsco.co/) for an example. I want the first image in my post to look like that header on the page....

Answer (score 2):

I have had trouble with that too. I suppose you want to use the image as a background image.
I worked around that using some jquery.
Your aim is a little bit different than mine, so I would suggest you actually add a class to your first image (may want to do that manually, or use javascript), get the source, add it as a background image to your header and hide the image tag (don't do that if repetition is intended)

Markup would then be something like:

```
<header class="imgbg"></header>
<div class="post">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
  <img src="#" class="first-img">
</div>
```

and jquery:

```
function getimgsrc(){
    $('.post').find('.first-img').each(function(n, image){
        var image = $(image);
        var thisurl = $(this).attr('src');
        $('.imgbg').css('background-image', 'url(' + thisurl + ')');      
        $('.first-img').remove();
    });
}
```

I built a codepen to illustrate this a bit better: http://codepen.io/bekreatief/pen/BaFnx